# How Do I Split a String by Periods but Ignore Salutations?

Tags: php, regex, text-parsing, preg-split

I am very much aware this is a non-trivial problem.

I've currently got this:

```
(.*?)(!,"\s|!,"$|\.\s|\.$|\!"?\s+?|\!"?$|\?"?\s+?|\?"?$|\."\s+?|\."$|…"\s+?|…"?$)
```

Which is matching various line-ending bits and splitting sentences/paragraphs. It's doing a very good job.

However, given the sentence:

```
Hello, Dr. Smith. How are you?
```

I'd like to split this in to:

1. `Hello, Dr. Smith.`
2. `How are you?`

My existing solution would produce something like:

1. `Hello, Dr.`
2. `Smith.`
3. `How are you?`

There's a whole set of salutations to (negatively) match:

```
Dr.|Prof.|Mr.|Mrs.|Ms.
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You want a negative lookbehind http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: and what is your question?...what do you want..make your question clear with example

Comment: This is quite tough. Also take the corner case "Hello, Dr. Smile." for example. In this case, "Smile" is a command and not a name, so if I understand what you want to do it should be split into 1) "Hello, Dr." 2) "Smile."

Comment: @DaveRandom - That's what I thought, but I'm having trouble integrating that in to my existing expression. Some guidance would be most appreciated.

Comment: @lc - True, but correct grammar would actually be "Hello, doctor. Smile." Or, "Hello, Doctor. Smile." Dr. is *supposed* to only come before the proper noun of one's name and I would be ok with an mis-match in this case.

Comment: Well for example [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HDtvOh) does the job - but whether that will work for you depends on what you want. That example splits on the whitespace character following the period - which means there would have to be at least one whitespace character or it won't work. Unfortunately it is necessary to include the period after each item in the lookbehind - in order to avoid this you would need to place a group within the lookbehind, which cannot do because the list items are not of a fixed width.

Comment: ...or you can just split on the lookbehind (like [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eUbzrx)) but if you do that then the whitespace character will be left on the beginning of the next item.

Comment: @DaveRandom - The whitespace requirement is 100% acceptable. Leaving the whitespace on the next line is fine, too. I'm still not sure how to have that rule run in conjunction with my existing rules, however. Thank you so much, so far. This is fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that you are staring down a rabbit hole.  If you choose to go down this path, prepare yourself for some unforeseen challenges.

As for your most immediate requirements, list your non-splitting matches then use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to discard these occurrences and go on to match the strings that should trigger a splitting point.

`\K` will reset the fullstring match.  This means that previously matched characters will not be removed in the explosion.  Only whitespace characters will be consumed while making these elements.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MIYDl))

```
$text = <<<TEXT
Dr. Di MacKusa is a doctor.  Do you know her?!?  She live on 1 Doctor Dr. Doctorsville in the U.S.A. Mr. MacKusa married Dr. Di.
TEXT;

var_export(
    preg_split(
        '~(?:Ms|Dr|Mrs?|Prof)\.(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[?!.]+\K\s+~',
        $text,
        0,
        PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Dr. Di MacKusa is a doctor.',
  1 => 'Do you know her?!?',
  2 => 'She live on 1 Doctor Dr. Doctorsville in the U.S.A.',
  3 => 'Mr. MacKusa married Dr. Di.',
)
```

With a more comprehensive sample text, I could improve my pattern.  My pattern is a rather simple solution that us not yet designed to correctly handle quoted text.